Estimating the distance in Riemannian manifold
Let $M$ and $N$ be Riemannian manifolds of the same dimension, and let $\phi : M \rightarrow N$ be a smooth map. Denote by $d_M$ and $d_N$ the respective Riemannian distances. Suppose that there is a point $p \in M$ such that the derivative $D \phi(p)$ is an isometry. I'm trying to prove the following estimate: for all $q$ close to $p$ one has that
$$
d_N(\phi(p), \phi(q)) = d_M(p, q) + O(d_M(p, q)^2).
$$
Even an exponent $\alpha > 1$ instead of $2$ would suffice.
How can one prove such a statement?
I would appreciate any help or references.
Thank you.

Take charts about $p$ and $\phi(p)$ and use them to push the problem back to $\Bbb R^n$.
